# DocuSign -- Is the Quick Start code generator working for other developers?

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I used the DocuSign [Quick Start](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/) web page to generate a C# webapp.  It compiles and runs fine.  I'm using the "default" MVC controller (Eg001EmbeddedSigningController) which will use embedded signing to let the user sign a document.  When the webapp runs, it prompts me to sign into my Sandbox account and then presents the "1. Embedded Signing Ceremony" page.  I fill in the Signer Email and Name and click Submit.  Next, the page from DocuSign with my document to sign is displayed and I click "Continue".

*My expectation:*  I expect the document to sign should already have a "Sign Here" element on the document, so all I have to do is click, sign, and finish.

*What I'm seeing:*  There are no "Sign Here" elements anywhere on the document.  I can add them manually (drag/drop), but that won't meet our needs.

I had assumed the document was using Anchor Tags to place the "Sign Here" elements -- at least it appears so from the code.  A different controller (Eg002SigningViaEmailController -- which sends out an email request to sign) specifically says it uses "Anchor Text (AutoPlace)", but the documents appear just like the first sample -- no "Sign Here" elements unless you add them manually.

So -- should I be seeing documents that have pre-placed "Sign Here" elements?  If so and since I'm not seeing that, any suggestions on why this sample code doesn't appear to work for me?  Or, am I missing something else here?

Please let me know if you have any questions or need more info.

thanks,
randy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I run the C# quickstart the "Sign Here" tab is already placed in the document with an Anchor tag. Does your code match the [code here on GitHub](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-csharp/blob/master/launcher-csharp/Eg001EmbeddedSigningController.cs#L164)? Specifically lines 152-164, where the Anchor Tab is defined and assigned to the signer.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Yes, my code does add the Anchor Tab just like the GitHub source. I also checked the document which is to be signed and the "/sn1/" Anchor text is present and matches the Anchor Tab being defined in the code.  I made a small mod to write the completed envelope definition as JSON to a temp file just before it's posted to DocuSign. It appears to be correct and well-formed. This is a bit strange -- it all should work fine, but I can't get it to. This leads me to believe something is amiss with how my Sandbox is setup. Thanks!

Comment: A DocuSign Developer representative said one item that was missing was each SignHere tag needed a DocumentId reference to associate it with its document.  Once I added those, the code worked fine.  I'm still confused why the sample code "out of the box" didn't work.  It may have something to do with the value of the Anchor Population Scope setting on my account (it's set to Document; the default is Envelope).  It's set to Document as part of a solution for sending out multiple documents each using the same server template.